# Can't open any files in Code::Blocks application during runtime

Tags: c++, file-io, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks to make an OpenGL program in C++. The program compiles and runs, but the texture is never displayed. I just get an empty grey rectangle against a white background, when there should have been a picture in the grey rectangle.

I first noticed problems when trying to load the images for textures using the Simple OpenGL Image Library (SOIL). I did some digging around in the code of SOIL and found that the program was not opening any files at all. I tried changing image format, creating some random text files to test, and more, but it would not open any files of any type.

I think I may have the files in the wrong directory, but if so, where are they supposed to go? Right now, I have them saved in the same directory as the code.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere, you are giving paths to the files. These should be relative to the location of the executable. So examples could be this:

```
someFunction("file.jpg");
```

Here, the file.jpg should be somewhere like: <project_dir>/bin/Debug/

```
someFunction("../../file.jpg");
```

Now the correct location will be: <project_dir>/

Comment: I tried adding the "../../" and moving the files to the Debug directory directly, but I still was unable to open the files. I tried copying the files to every possible directory I could think of, and it still would not work. Finally, I decided to try using the full path to the file, and then the program crashed. When windows told me it couldn't find a solution to the problem, the program exited with status 255. I realized that the jpg file I was trying to use was "locked" because I got it from the internet, but even after unlocking it the program would crash and return 255. Other suggestions?

Comment: Without code, one can but guess. My guess would be that you haven't changed back what you did when you `tried changing image format`, but just giving a minimal sample that has this problem would be a much better strategy for both of us.

Comment: I'm using the SOIL library, but any file I try to open gives me an error. The code in SOIL that opens the file is as follows:


unsigned char *stbi_load(char const *filename, int *x, int *y, int *comp, int req_comp)
{
   FILE *f = fopen(filename, "rb");
   unsigned char *result;
   if (f) return ("File opened");
   if (!f) return epuc("can't fopen", "Unable to open file");
   result = stbi_load_from_file(f,x,y,comp,req_comp);
   fclose(f);
   return result;
}

Comment: `if (f) return ("File opened");` prevents this code from doing what it is supposed to do. Also, from this I can still only guess. Could you please provide a minimal sample? (= a sample with as little code as possible that does have the problem)

Comment: I created a text file to test this out. The code is

FILE *file = fopen ("Hello.txt, "rb");

if (!file) return 7;

This would be the entire main method. I put the return just to double check that it was exiting at that point. The program will just exit returning 7.